# Trying to install psi4 and pyopencap in Anacaonda3 over windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I was trying to install psi4 and pyopencap for some molecular project with anaconda3, but I receive a lot of env conflicts and it aborts the installation. I tried that using python as well, but it doesn't go easier. The only way it worked was using the Datalore notebook, but that comes at a cost. I have python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10 installed. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since `pyopencap` is not on Conda, one would install it through `pip`. However, I was not able to get it to compile correctly for Windows. You would probably be better off running through WSL, since these tools are primarily developed on Linux (and note the environment below works just fine on **linux-64** and **osx-64**).

Here was the environment that went the furthest:

[image: so-pyopencap]

**so-pyopencap.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-pyopencap
channels:
  - psi4
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  ## core
  - python=3.8
  - pip
  
  ## build components
  - compilers
  - cmake
  - eigen
  - hdf5
  
  ## Conda Python packages
  - psi4
  
  ## PyPI packages
  - pip:
      - pyopencap
```

The error in [a GitHub Actions run](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/actions/runs/2241505405) shows CMake complaining about not having Visual Studio 16 2019. Windows compilation isn't my domain of expertise, but the documentation references C++17, so possibly the C/C++ compilers Conda provides on the Windows side aren't compatible?